# Twitter Bootstrap typeahead response ordering collapsed

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

When the user types abc, the typeahead sends ajax requests for a and then ab and then abc.
If a's response comes after abc's response, it ends up showing the suggestion for a instead of abc.
How to resolve this issue?

I have given my JSON Response and the javascript code. But this question is independent of the code i think.

My JSON Response:

```
{
    "tt": 0.24989604949951172,  
    "suggestions": [  
        "hurt locker",  
        "hunger games",  
    ],  
}
```

My JavaScript Code:

```
function typeahead_fn() {
       var map = {};
       $this = $(this);
       $this.typeahead({
             source: function (query, process) {
                     return $.get("/kgraphsearch/", { w: query }, function (data) {
                                     $('#surl').html(data.search_query);
                                     $('#surl').attr("href", data.search_query);
                                     return process(data.suggestions);
                                 });
             },
             matcher: function (param) {return true},
             sorter: function (items) {
                  return items;
                  // implementation
             },
             property: 'name',
             items: 5,
             updater: function(item) {
                  return item;
             },
             onselect: function(item) { 
                  console.log(item);
                  return item;
             }
    });
}  
$(".typeahead").each(typeahead_fn);
```

Comment: That's strange but pretty sure the server would respond to the abc request last and response would be abc.

Comment: My server is a multi threaded server which can handle concurrent requests. Also, the prefix query with one or two letters takes more time than the 3 or more letter query.

Comment: Okay, is it possible you can send back the request query in the JSON result, then compare this against the current value in the text box and only show the results if it's a match?

Comment: On similar lines of @Stokedout, One solution that i can think of is client should send the timestamp of the request to the server. Server should bounce back the timestamp. Client should not render the response if the timestamp given in response is less than the last rendered timestamp. This will work. But i am thinking, whether twitter bootstrap itself has some built-in solutions.